# Matplotlib error occurs first time I run Jupyter cell but not second time

Tags: python, matplotlib, runtime-error

The first time, but not subsequent times, I run this code block I get an error. Can anyone help me understand why please?

There are no previous SO posts on this error at all (at least in search results)

I am fairly new to coding. As far as I can tell it is a sequence error in my code. Namely, the first time the attribute isn't loaded (yet), then the attribute gets loaded further down the code block, making it available when I run the code again. Problem is I can't work out what part of the code it is.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

%matplotlib notebook

def data_gen(t=0):
    cnt = 0
    while cnt < 150:
        cnt += 1
        t += 0.1
        yield t, np.sin(2*np.pi*t) * np.exp(-t/10.)


def init():
    ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 1.1)
    ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
    del xdata[:]
    del ydata[:]
    line.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return line,

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
ax.grid()
xdata, ydata = [], []


def run(data):
    # update the data
    t, y = data
    xdata.append(t)
    ydata.append(y)
    xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()

    if t >= xmax:
        ax.set_xlim(xmin, 2*xmax)
        ax.figure.canvas.draw()
    line.set_data(xdata, ydata)

    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, run, data_gen, blit=False, interval=15,
                              repeat=False, init_func=init)                                   

plt.show()
```

**Error Message**

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/alexfreeman/Documents/Dev/AnacondaInstall/anaconda/envs/py3-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py",
> line 387, in process
>     proxy(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/alexfreeman/Documents/Dev/AnacondaInstall/anaconda/envs/py3-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py",
> line 227, in __call__
>     return mtd(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/alexfreeman/Documents/Dev/AnacondaInstall/anaconda/envs/py3-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py",
> line 1499, in _stop
>     self.event_source.remove_callback(self._loop_delay) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_callback'
```

Comment: Thanks again @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. About the edit you did on the question, did you change it from quote block to code block? I was wondering what the correct way to post stack trace was. That's helpful to know.

Comment: The stacktrace should be in a code environment, because otherwise characters like underscore or star get interpreted as markup. You may put additionally put it in a yellow box, but I personally find that rather distracting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the order of importing matplotlib.pyplot and setting the `notebook` backend matters.

When putting the `%matplotlib notebook` line on top, it works fine for me

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
```

Comment: You're onto something here but since you gave me this answer I have discovered another problem. I have 2 plots in separate cells in one Jupyter notebook. One has "%matplotlib inline" and one has "%matplotlib notebook" and I can't find a way to switch between them without the error on the first run of the cell, second run it works fine.

Comment: It's still not perfect but it's not super critical. The combination of your answer and the linked answer make the error less frequent. Thank again for your help.

Comment: A bug in the code sometimes requires to **use the command twice** as mentioned here: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10873